# config for using git via ssh on jump host

Tags: ssh-keys

With a private key that is only available on a laptop (alice), is there a way to use that key for authentication with gitlab from a server (bob). (Minor, I think, complication being a jump host between alice and bob.)

alice --> jump --> bob --> gitlab

The ~/.ssh/config on alice is currently:

```
Host *
  PKCS11Provider /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib

Host jump
  HostName jump01.example.org

Host bob
  HostName bob.example.org
  ProxyJump jump
```

I've got the public key from alice's token on gitlab, and I'd like to use it with `git` commands from bob. As in...

```
alice:~ $ ssh bob
Last login: Fri Aug 27 20:33:56 2021
bob:~ $ git clone git@gitlab.example.org:my/repo.git
```

where I've got no key pair on bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have some trust that `bob` can't be abused, but the simple answer is to run an ssh-agent, and use agent forwarding.

Start an agent on `alice`, add your PKCS11Provider using `ssh-add -S` then configuring agent forwarding in your config.

```
Host bob
  ForwardAgent yes
  HostName bob.example.org
  ProxyJump jump
```

See the man pages for ssh-agent, ssh-add, and ssh_config for details about the PKCS11 providers, and agent forwarding.

> Minor, I think, complication being a jump host

Because of how ProxyJump works, it is not a complication, and literally doesn't matter at all. From the perspective of the ssh client on Alice, it acts exactly like you made a direct connection to Bob.